# What is the meaning of $i^{\sigma ^{−1}}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, terminology

A string $x$ is a map $\Omega \rightarrow \Sigma$ from a finite set $\Omega$ of positions to a finite set $\Sigma$ of letters, the alphabet.

Let  $\Sigma^\Omega $ denote the set of all strings.
In examples we will write strings simply as chains of characters, e.g. $x = raspberry$ for $\Omega = \{1, \cdots 9\}$ and the lower case English alphabet$\Sigma= \{a, \cdots z\}$ .

The action of $\text{Sym}(\Omega)$ on $\Omega$ induces an action on $\Sigma^\Omega $.

For $ \sigma \in \text{Sym}(\Omega)$ and $x \in \Sigma^\Omega $, the string $x^\sigma $ is defined [in this document (page 4)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.10260) by:

> $x^\sigma  (i) = x(i^{\sigma ^{−1}})$ for all $i \in \Omega$.

What is the meaning of $i^{\sigma ^{−1}}$?

Is $i$ the $i^{th}$ position in $x$? For example, if $x = raspberry$  then $x(2)=a$? Then if $\sigma = (12)$, $x^\sigma  (2)=arspberry$, right? then why the author used the inverse of $\sigma$ on $i$ in $x(i^{\sigma ^{−1}})$?

It would be natural to use $i^{\sigma}$ instead of $i^{\sigma ^{−1}}$, though author mentions, that "This twist is necessary in order to have .." I don't understand what author meant here.

Comment: In your example, with $\sigma=(12)$, there's no difference between $\sigma$ and $\sigma^{-1}$. Also, $x^\sigma(2)$ is just $r$, the second character in $x^\sigma=arspberry$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the meaning of $i^{\sigma^{-1}}$?

The paper defines $i^{\sigma^{-1}} = \sigma^{-1}(i)$.

> Is $i$ the $i$th position in $x$?

We're told $i \in \Omega$, so $i$ itself has nothing to do with $x$ except that it ought to be in the domain of $x$.

In contrast, $x(i)$ is the image of $i$ under the map $x : \Omega \to \Sigma$, which in this particular case can be identified as the $i$th character of the string $x$.

> For example, if $x=\mathrm{raspberry}$, then $x(2) = \mathrm{a}$?

Yes.

> Then if $\sigma = (12)$, $x^\sigma(2) = \mathrm{arspberry}$, right?

No.  Rather, you have $x^\sigma = \mathrm{arspberry}$ and $x^\sigma(2) = \mathrm{r}$.

---

**And now we finally reach your question:** (in the future, it would be better to spotlight your actual question rather than your first question)

> then why the author used the inverse of $\sigma$ on $i$ in $x(i^{\sigma^{-1}})$?

**Short answer:** We want to define $x^\sigma$ so that $(x^\sigma)^\tau = x^{\sigma\tau}$ and without the twist, we'd have $(x^\sigma)^\tau = x^{\tau\sigma}$ instead.  Therefore the twist is required.

**Longer answer:** This depends on how we define products of permutations in the symmetric group.  Unfortunately, the author of the paper didn't deem it necessary to explicitly mention how to evaluate products in the preliminaries section, but they did give us their reference for "a comprehensive introduction" to permutation groups: Dixon and Mortimer's *Permutation Groups*.  Looking it up, we find this on page 3:

> Our convention is to consider permutations as functions acting on the right. This means that a product $xy$ of permutations should be read as: first apply $x$ and then $y$

In other words, in the current context, $(\sigma\tau)(i) = (\tau\circ \sigma)(i) = \tau(\sigma(i))$, which might feel backwards to you and is probably why the author of the paper prefers the alternative notation $i^\sigma = \sigma(i)$, as under this notation,
$$i^{\sigma\tau} = (\sigma\tau)(i) = \tau(\sigma(i)) = \tau(i^\sigma) = (i^\sigma)^\tau.$$
That is, $i^{\sigma\tau} = (i^\sigma)^\tau$, which is much better!  Anyway, this choice has the effect of forcing us to use a twist when defining $x^\sigma$.

*If instead we defined $x^\sigma$ without the twist as* $x^\sigma(i) = x(i^\sigma)$: Then we'd have
$$x^{\sigma\tau}(i) = x(i^{\sigma\tau}) = x((i^\sigma)^\tau) = x^\tau(i^\sigma) = (x^\tau)^\sigma(i)\\ \implies x^{\sigma\tau} = (x^\tau)^\sigma$$
Note that the order has been "messed up" without the twist.

*When defining $x^\sigma$ with the twist* as $x^\sigma(i) = x(i^{\sigma^{-1}})$:  Then we have
$$x^{\sigma\tau}(i) = x\left(i^{(\sigma\tau)^{-1}}\right) = x\left(i^{\tau^{-1}\sigma^{-1}}\right) = x\left(\left(i^{\tau^{-1}}\right)^{\sigma^{-1}}\right) = x^\sigma\left(i^{\tau^{-1}}\right) = (x^\sigma)^\tau(i) \\ \implies x^{\sigma\tau} = (x^\sigma)^\tau$$
and the order is nice, once more!

---

A couple final remarks:

- Note that the paper has a typo in the middle of equation (2.1) when showing that the twist yields the preferred result of $x^{\sigma\tau} = (x^\sigma)^\tau$.  I've corrected it in my version I've shown here.
- Even if you chose the convention that permutations act on the left, you'd probably still want to use a twist when defining the action of a permutation $\sigma$ on the function $x$.  This is because the twist preserves both left actions and right actions, while the untwisted version turns left actions into right actions and vice versa.

Comment: @MRJames2017 No.  Without the twist we'd have the order reversed as I've written.  I can't quite understand your second question, but inverting a permutation has the effect of essentially reversing it, so it does have an effect...

Comment: Ah I missed the implication sign, got it, I meant that the permutation will be always applied inversely, so it will be consistent ...it is like a country changing the rule to  right side driving  from left side driving, if everybody follows the rule, there is no effect.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is the image of $i$ under $\sigma^{-1}$.

Comment: It is. Definition 2.1 makes this explicit.

Comment: @TheoBendit I wanted to know why author used the inverse of a permutation, I understand  it is the image of $i$ but why the inverse?

Comment: @MRJames2017 I haven't read it in detail, but the author seems to address this in the next sentence. They want (2.1), i.e. $x^{\sigma \tau} = (x^\sigma)^\tau$, to hold.

Comment: @TheoBendit my dear friend you are missing my point, he is using inverse of the permutation that acts on $i$, why? The entire page tells nothing about it, let alone the second line!

Comment: @MRJames2017 Oh! It seems I did miss the point. What else is $\sigma$, a permutation of the finite position set $\Omega$ supposed to act on? I'm not sure what the alternative is here.

Comment: @TheoBendit  it would be natural to use $i^{\sigma}$ instead of $i^{\sigma ^{−1}}$, though author mentions, that "This twist is necessary in order to have .." I don't understand what author meant here.

Comment: It would be best to ask a new question about this, @MRJames2017.

Comment: @MRJames2017 Without the twist, you would instead get $(x^\sigma)^\tau = x^{\tau \sigma}$. I'm guessing that nothing goes disastrously wrong, but I suspect it makes the exposition cleaner going forward.

Comment: @Shawn Please feel free to edit what we've collectively uncovered in the comments into your answer. I think that would be easier than re-asking and re-answering the question.

Comment: @Shaun why should I  repeat the question?

Comment: @TheoBendit I have checked other papers, they use the same thing, but don't get why, that is why I am seeking help here, there might be good reason for this.

Comment: @MRJames2017 This isn't my field, so I can't comment on larger trends here, but I would say that ensuring $(x^\sigma)^\tau$ equals the "nicer" expression $x^{\sigma \tau}$, instead of $x^{\tau \sigma}$, is reason enough for this to become convention. There may be other reasons that only the experts may be able to uncover. Perhaps another person has more insight into this.

Comment: @TheoBendit, but wouldn't the definition without the inverse also give $(x^\sigma)^\tau=x^{\sigma\tau}$? I.e., $$(x^\sigma)^\tau(i)=x^\sigma(i^\tau)=x^\sigma(\tau(i))=x((\tau(i))^\sigma)=x(\sigma(\tau(i))=x((\sigma\tau)(i))=x(i^{\sigma\tau})=x^{\sigma\tau}(i)$$

Comment: @BarryCipra That is an excellent point. Then, I have no idea why the inverse is necessary.

Comment: @BarryCipra Iirc, some people define the product of permutations so that the action on is on the right.  In that case, you'd have $\sigma(\tau(i)) = (\tau\sigma)(i)$.  It doesn't play well with the left-sided function notation, but it's possible this is where the confusion lies: left actions v. right actions.

Comment: @BrianMoehring, that would explain it, but the paper's equation (2.1) pretty clearly indicates that  $i^{(\sigma\tau)^{-1}}=(i^{\sigma^{-1}})^{\tau^{-1}}$, which, given that $i^\pi=\pi(i)$, means $(\tau^{-1}\sigma^{-1})(i)=\tau^{-1}(\sigma^{-1}(i))$

Comment: @BarryCipra That's a typo that tripped me up for a bit for precisely the reason you mention.  If you assume it's not a typo, though, the next equality in that sequence is just nonsense.

Comment: @BrianMoehring, ah, that makes sense. Thanks! (I didn't see that you had already posted an answwer explaining all this. Sorry about that.)